# div fade in on mousemove, no fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The goal is to have the #content div fade in after the page has loaded and after the mouse moves. This only happens on the homepage. #content on all other pages do not fade in.

I know how to achieve most of this in CSS. That is, I can get the #content on only the homepage to fade in after the page loads. Trying to work out the mousemove part.

I've read through all the similar posts, most of which involve fading out as well. Here is what I've put together so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("html").on('mousemove', function(){
        $("#content").stop().fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

I also tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("html").mousemove(function(){
        $("#content").stop().fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Those scripts are in the `<head>`.

In the CSS, I have

```
.fadeonmouse{
    opacity: .0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

.fadeonmouse in a class of the #content div only on the homepage. I am using the following php:

```
<div id="content" class="site-content <?php if( is_page(get_option('page_on_front')) ) { ?>fadeonmouse<?php } ?>">
```

I have also come across a method where people use `onmousemove="function()"`
right in the div tag. I haven't been able to get that to work either.

I'm new to javascript but I'm solid with CSS. Is there a way to trigger a CSS animation after the mouse moves? I just want the div to fade in, permanently, after the page loads and the mouse is moved. Thank you!

Comment: Are there any major differences between the content on the first page vs all of the other pages?  Also, how are the other pages loaded?  Normal navigation or something special?

Comment: what about a css animationof opacity  for `body:hover #content` selector in CSS?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to proceed with Jquery + CSS, try Jquery animate method

```
$("#content").animate({
            opacity:1
        },500);
```

jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/yehzp2rL/